# Event when a pair of elements are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have 5 elements with class `.home` and unique id's, and a button with class `.btn1`. When `.home` is clicked after `.btn1` and vice versa, a function should be executed. I don't know what jQuery method i should use.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .active {
            background-color: skyblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="home">I am Div1</div>
        <div class="home">I am Div2</div>
        <div class="home">I am Div3</div>
        <div class="home">I am Div4</div>
        <div class="home">I am Div5</div>
        <button class="btn">Run</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var divReady = false;
            var btnReady = false;
            $(".btn").on("click",function(){
                btnReady = true;
                $(this).addClass("active");
                if (divReady)
                    fun();
            })
            $("div").on("click",function(){
                divReady = true;
                $("div").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                if (btnReady)
                    fun();
            })
            
            function fun() {
                alert("I am working!")
                $(".btn,div").removeClass("active");
                btnReady = false;
                divReady = false;
            }
            
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply count the times an event occured, and store the events. That can be easily done with an Array:

```
//create an array to store events
events=[];
//create a handler function
function handler(event){
//add the event to our array
events.push(event);
if(events.length==2){
//two events fired:
//first event:
a=events[0];
//second:
b=events[1];
//do whatever
}
}
//add an eventlistener that calls our handler and passes 'documentclick'   
 document.addEventListener("documentclick",function(){handler("click")});
```

Comment: could you provide a snippet with a simple example, to better understand your answer?

Comment: @Lukas Baliūnas: the example is self explaining, please describe what you exactly dont understand

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a specific jQuery trick for that.

Why not use classes to store state?

```js
        $(function() {

            $(".home").click(function () {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                if ($(".btn1").hasClass("active")) {
                    console.log("Doing something");
                }

            });


            $(".btn1").click(function () {
                        $(this).addClass("active");
                        if ($(".home").hasClass("active")) {
                            console.log("Doing something");
                        }
                    }
            );
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'home'>
        Home
    </div>
    <div>
        Stuff
    </div>
    <button class = 'btn1' >Button</button>
    <div class = 'home'>
        Home
    </div>
    <div>
        Stuff
    </div>
    <div class = 'home'>
        Home
    </div>
    <div>
        Stuff
    </div>
    <div class = 'home'>
        Home
    </div>
    <div>
        Stuff
    </div>
```